# Egit message not authorized and no way to change user name

Tags: eclipse, plugins, egit

Using Zend PHP Eclipse for developers with the latest version of egit.

1. Entered and stored correct credentials
2. Check out the code
3. Tried to commit
4. Not Authorized

Can't change the user name under any circumstances

Preferences -> General -> Security -> Secure Storage -> Contents

Can be cleared but also not editable.

Open Git repositories view,
open "Remotes > origin > "
click "Change Credentials..."
Doesn't allow to change credentials.

All I want to be able to do is enter the correct credentials.